# Unhandled AggregateException on Tasks Continuation thrown on another OS

Tags: c#, wcf, task-parallel-library, continuations, aggregateexception

I'm getting a strange behavior in a winForms application while testing to see how it responds on different OS.

The long running operation where the unhandled `AggregateException` is thrown ( when tested on a XP 32bit machine) is part of a WCF (using `basicHttpBinding` and `Streamed` transfer mode) client update procedure. The structure is similar to the following code snippet. I have ommited WCF exception handling for clarity:

```
var tsUIthread = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
int filesCount = 0;
List<MessageContract> files;

private void Update()
{
    var cTokenDownloadFiles = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var cTokenUpdateDatabases = new CancellationTokenSource();

    var task1CheckForNewFiles = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
    {
        filesCount = proxy.GetFiles();
        If(filesCount == 0)
        {
            cTokenDownloadFiles.Cancel();
            cTokenUpdateDatabases.Cancel();
        }
        else
            files = new List<MessageContract>();
    });


    var task2UpdateControls = task1CheckForNewFiles.ContinueWith(result => 
    {
        UpdateControlsBeforeDownload();

    }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, tsUIthread);


    var task3DownloadFiles = task2.ContinueWith(result => 
    {
        for(int i = 0; i< filesCount; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                files.Add(proxy.DownloadFile());
            }
            catch(IOException)
            {
                cTokenUpdateDatabases.Cancel();
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ResetControls, 
                    CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, tsUIthread);
                retryUpdateTimer.Start(); // System.Windows.Forms.Timer
                return;
            }
        }    

    }, cTokenDownloadFiles.Token);


    var task4UpdateDatabases = task3DownloadFiles.ContinueWith(result =>
    {            
        UpdateDatabases();

    },cTokenUpdateDatabases.Token);


    var task5UpdateControls = task4UpdateDatabases.ContinueWith(result =>
    {
        UpdateControlsOnUpdateFinished();

    }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, tsUIthread);

}
```

You'll notice that I wrap the `proxy.DownloadFile()` method in a try-catch block where I'm trapping an `IO.IOException`. As I meantioned in the beggining of my post, my WCF services use the `Streamed` transfer mode of the `basicHttpBinding` so I need to catch this type of exception when for some reason the connection to the server is lost after the operation has begun. All I do In the catch statement is, cancelling the databases update task, reset the UI controls to their primary values and start a System.Windows.Forms.Timer with an `Interval` of a few seconds what will execute the `Update()` method again if the client has internet connectivity.

While this whole procedure works as expected on my dev environment (Windows7 32bit machine) when an `IOException` is thrown ,  when I test my winforms Application on a Windows XP 32bit machine an unhandled `AggregateException` at `System.Threading.Tasks.ExceptionHolder.Finalize()` terminates the Application.

Has anyone experienced anything similar? How is it possible for the exception to be thrown only on the XP machine? I still haven't tested it on other environments.
The actual code contains more tasks and continuations, calling downstream business components and I'm kind of lost when it comes to Task exception handling with continuations spaghetti. Could you give me some examples of how I should structure the exception handling?

Comment: What exceptions is the `AggregateException` holding in its `InnerExceptions` property?

Comment: You can subscribe to the [TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception.aspx) static event to see them.

Comment: I don't really know, thats part of what I'm asking as well, how to handle my tasks on multiple long running tasks continuations.

After the exception is thrown the Application shuts down on the XP machine. I'm reading the exception from the event viewer.

Comment: Have you ever noticed anything similar with TPL ?

Comment: @NicholasButler after examining the `UnobservedTaskException` it seems that after the `IOException` is caught, the program scedules and executes task4UpdateDatabases, despite the fact that I explicitly cancel its `CancellationToken`, `cTokenUpdateDatabases.Cancel()`. The updateDatabases task runs some service operations as well for which I haven't added WCF exception handling yet. Again this happens only the XP machine, on the windows 7 development machine everything goes as expected, task4UpdateDatabases and next tasks are not getting scheduled and the operation starts again from the timer.

Comment: Ok it's not a TPL related issue. It's WCF. I'm catching an `EndpointNotFoundException` on the Windows 7 machine while on Windows XP in catching a `CommunicationException` which is the base class for `EndpointNotFound`.